# Why android log cat not showing debug statement in LOGV("....");

Tags: android

In framework/base native C++ code, I see code with log statements like

```
 LOGV(".....");
```

But on phone when I use 'adb logcat', why I am not seeing those log statements. 
I see LOGD("....), though.

Is there anything I need to do in order to see 'LOGV(...)'?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Android doesn't output Verbose level logs for native (C/C++) code. If you want those logs for debugging you can redefine LOGV to LOGD in native code.

For eg. #define LOGV LOGD in the beginning of any source file that you need logs from.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
adb logcat *:V
```

[Android ABD Filtering Log Output](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html)

> The following filter expression displays all log messages with
>   priority level "warning" and higher, on all tags:
>
> adb logcat *:W